# Se puede hacer zoom a imagen que incluye botones guardando la relación de aspecto? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo una imagen dentro de un layout de android y dentro de la imagen quiero incluir varios botones (Corresponden a los recuadros en blanco de la imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Querría saber cómo podría hacer zoom a la imagen guardando la relación de aspecto con los botones para poder pulsarlos tras la ampliación dado que sin ampliar son botones muy pequeños.

Muchas gracias y disculpen las molestias.

Comment: Anteriormente esta misma pregunta fue cerrada en dos ocasiones por ser "Demasiado" amplia, te sugiero revisar como realizar preguntas en el sitio para que obtengas la ayuda adecuada., Nuevamente te invitamos a revisar [ask] y realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos!

Comment: Buenas Jorge, sé que es una pregunta muy amplia pero no se me ocurre como resumirla, solo quiero saber si alguien tiene un ejemplo parecido o algo. No sé si me explico bien pero lo que quiero es ampliar la imagen y luego poder pulsar los botones que tengo dentro de ella básicamente.